# How can we get number of textboxes in a form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, textbox

How can we get number of textboxes in a form using javascript?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var count = 0;
for(var cpt = 0; cpt < inputs.length; cpt++)
if (inputs[cpt].type == 'text') count++;
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var c=0;
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    var node = node_list[i];

     if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        c++;
     }
 } 
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).length;
```

But it won't separate input types.  If you have to do that, create the array like I did above then loop through the array and select members that are the right type, then check length on the resulting array.

```
(function () {
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('input')),
    i = arr.length, item, textOnlyArray = [];
    while (i--) {
        item = arr[i];
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("type") && item.type === "text") {
            textOnlyArray.push(item);
        }
    }
    return textOnlyArray;
}());
```

You can also use Array.forEach if you don't need to support old/junky browsers.  That's even faster than while(i--)

Comment: ... but inaccurate, since it will count all types of `<input>`, not just text boxes.

Comment: hasOwnProperty is so misused... do you use it here because you modified Object's prototype? That's a bad idea in the first place. The real problem with hasOwnProperty is that you lose the ability to check for inherited properties. GôTô's answer is simpler and clearer

Comment: I'm checking the DOM node's property, so I don't want inherited properties.  The Object property was not modified.  I think you misunderstand what .apply() does.